# How to reuse KafkaListenerContainerFactory with a custom message converter for batch listeners and non-batch/record listeners?

Tags: spring-kafka

The [`spring-kafka` documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#batch-listeners) mentions:

> Starting with version 2.8, you can override the factory’s batchListener propery using the batch property on the @KafkaListener annotation. This, together with the changes to Container Error Handlers allows the same factory to be used for both record and batch listeners.

I want to use it like this. So reuse the same factory for record and batch listeners. The factory is provided by an internal library that is used by multiple services.

However, I also need to define a custom `MessageConverter`.

But I found out that for batch listeners I need to wrap my message converter in `BatchMessagingMessageConverter` otherwise the message converter will not be used correctly and the wrong type will be supplied to my batch listener.

So: **Is there a simple way to reuse `KafkaListenerContainerFactory` with a custom messageConverter for batch listeners and non-batch/record listeners?**

---

My current workaround looks like this, but I do not like it as it depends on how `spring-kafka` internally sets up its configuration, so it might break in future updates:

```java
factory.setContainerCustomizer(container -> {
    var messageListener = container.getContainerProperties().getMessageListener();
    if (messageListener instanceof FilteringBatchMessageListenerAdapter) {
        var meessageListenerDelegate =
                ((FilteringBatchMessageListenerAdapter<?, ?>) messageListener).getDelegate();
        if (meessageListenerDelegate instanceof BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter) {
            ((BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter<?, ?>) meessageListenerDelegate).setBatchMessageConverter(
                    new BatchMessagingMessageConverter(messageConverter));
        }
    }
});
```

---

Another option is to create a separate factory for batch listeners. With this, I am afraid that someone might use `@KafkaListener(batch="true")` without supplying the correct library, which only works partly.

---

Currently, I am using version 2.8.9 of spring-kafka.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not currently possible; please open a new feature suggestion on GitHub to allow provisioning both types of converter on the factory.

Comment: Thank you. I opened https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2566.